# Iframe in Angular to a page on the same server

Tags: angular, iframe

I have a component with HTML containing just a iFrame to a HTML page on the same server.

```
<p>widget showing</p>
<iframe src="widget.html"></iframe>
```

In the App it shows "widget showing", but the iFrame contains the "index.html" of the App. Repeating the App and not showing the content of "widget.html".
This "widget.html" page is copied in the `dist/assets` folder, the  same level of "favicon.ico".

If I change it into `<iframe src="favicon.ico"></iframe>` the icon is visible.

So, why is my "widget.html" page not showing. I got the impression, Angular router is maybe in charge?

And how can I activate a HTML page, as an iFrame, from my server location?

`<iframe src="https://awebsite.com"></iframe>` will work, but not to this local HTML file.

Comment: Try `assets/widget.html`. I am pretty sure you get HTTP 404 for your current `widget.html` request because your web server can't find the page.

Comment: You're completely right! I've used 'favicon.ico' as a reference point. But there are two, also in `assets` and in root of the src. I referenced it wrongly, THX.